# TYPO3 7.4 display categories

Tags: typo3, categories, typoscript

I'm trying to display the categories of the current page.
Because I'm not that good in TYPO3, I first tried displaying **all** the categories before trying to display the **current** one.
The following snippet somehow doesn't work.

```
lib.categorized_content = RECORDS
lib.categorized_content {
    categories.field = selected_categories
    categories.relation.field = category_field
    tables = tt_content
    conf.tt_content = TEXT
    conf.tt_content {
        stdWrap.field = header
        stdWrap.typolink.parameter = {field:pid}
        stdWrap.typolink.parameter.insertData = 1
        stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>
    }
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
}
```

This is where I got this snippet from: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Records/Index.html#categories

I'm using `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.categorized_content" />` to implement it into my template.

Can someone help?

Comment: categories.field = 1,3 [categories UIDs] instead of categories.field = selected_categories and categories.relation.field = actual_field_name like uid instead of categories.relation.field = category_field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selected_categories` and `category_field` are flexform field (as you can see from the suffix `.field` of the configuration property) from the `Special Menu` content element.
You have to replace those with the actual value.